# Associate Simple Product to Configurable Product

Tags: php, mysql, magento, zend-framework, magento-1.9

Hi I am able to associate simple product to Configurable Product.
Using Code:

```
<?php
    require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
     umask(0);
     Mage::app();
    $productId= 86971;
    $productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id','configurable')
             ->load($productId); 

   foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
           $simpleProductIds = array('35683'); // Simple product Ids
       Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')
       ->saveProducts($product, $simpleProductIds);
}

?>
```

---

But whenever I associate new simple product to configurable product, I am loosing old associated product. Can you please help me out on this.

Thank You in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You're losing the old associations because saveProducts re-establishes the associations for a parent product with the product IDs you pass it. If you want to append a new product instead, you'll need to grab the old child product list, add the new product ID, and then call saveProducts with the resulting combined array.

```
$childProducts = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getChildrenIds($productId)
$childProducts[] = '35683';
Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')->saveProducts($productId, $childProducts);
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass $productid directly without foreach loop?

Comment: HI its showing duplicate entry whenever I am using this method